# Handle duplicating keys while mapping

Tags: java, java-8, duplicates, mapping

my problem is that I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key` every time I try to map a `String` with `List`. Is there a way to edit this implementation to somehow handle duplicate keys? Or should I do it in another way?

```
Map<String, List<Fee>> feeAccountMap = ContractList
            .stream()
            .filter(o -> !o.getStatus().equals(ContractStatus.CLOSED))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.getFeeAccount(), o -> {
                List<Fee> monthlyFees;
                try {
                    monthlyFees = contractFeeService.getContractMonthlyFees(o);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                return monthlyFees;
            }
            ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a merge function. For example:

```
Map<String, List<Fee>> feeAccountMap = ContractList
            .stream()
            .filter(o -> !o.getStatus().equals(ContractStatus.CLOSED))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.getFeeAccount(), o -> {
                List<Fee> monthlyFees;
                try {
                    monthlyFees = contractFeeService.getContractMonthlyFees(o);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                return monthlyFees;
            }, (value1, value2) -> value1
            ));
```

Since the value of your `Map` seems to be a function of the key, you can simply return one of the values when you have two values having the the same key.

This is assuming that if two elements of `ContractList` return the same `String` for `getFeeAccount()`, they are equal to each other.